# Comparable uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java, warnings

I am having trouble with a sorting class I am trying to implement. 
I don't want to override the compareTo method which I have in my other class, but if I do not make this class abstract that's what it asks me to do.
Is there someway I can get around this?

compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(Course other)
{
    if(this.getPoints() > other.getPoints())
        return 1;
    else if(this.getPoints() == other.getPoints())
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Sorting class

```
public abstract class Sorting implements Comparable<Course>
```

{

```
public static void Sorting(Comparable[] arr)
{
    int min; 
    Comparable temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(int scan = i + 1; scan < arr.length; scan++)
        {
            if(arr[scan].compareTo(arr[min]) < 0)
                min = scan;

                temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }   
}//end Sorting  
}//end class Sorting
```

These are the errors/warnings I get

```
    Sorting.java:14: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member
 of the raw type Comparable
                                if(arr[scan].compareTo(arr[min]) < 0)
                                                      ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
Sorting.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                                        temp = arr[min];
                                                  ^
  required: Comparable<Course>
  found:    Comparable
2 warnings
```

I am assuming it is because the compareTo takes in Course other, but I am passing in arr[min], and if that's it, how can I change it to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
    public int compareTo(Course other){...}  
    ...
}
```

and

```
public abstract class Sorting {
    public static void sorting(Course[] arr){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
            int min = i;
            for(int scan = i + 1; scan < arr.length; scan++)  {
                if(arr[scan].compareTo(arr[min]) < 0){
                   min = scan;
                }
                Course temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }   
    }//end Sorting  
}
```

Alternatively, you might simply use

```
public static void sorting(Course[] arr){
    Arrays.sort( arr );
}
```

Comment: The only problem with using Arrays.sort() for this particular problem is that I have been asked to either use the selectionsort or insertionsort algorithms.

Comment: Well, then don't - use your own method. I didn't say you can't.

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors when I implement this. It has something to do with the compareTo. No matter how I change it it's the same method that's causing different problems.

Comment: I have filled in the (slightly modified) code of method sorting. It compiles and works correctly.